# What is the short-cut key for commenting region in C++ mode in emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs

In C mode, I conveniently used <kbd>M-;</kbd> to comment region with the `/* */` style.

```
/* Program: Foo                  */
/* Author:  Jando                */
/* Date:    19/06/2014           */
/* ...                           */
```

Now I come to C++ mode, only to find that <kbd>M-;</kbd> can only do the comment line style with `//`.

```
// Only
// Comment Line
// is
// available here
```

May I know what is the key-binding in C++ mode of emacs to do comment region (`/*...*/`)? I really need this style to write comments such as the source file header region (because my company has this format to conform to).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ mode, the variable `comment-start` and `comment-end`'s value are `"// "` and `""`, while in C mode they are `"/* "` and `" */"`.

So you can change the local variable to attain the same behaviour as C mode, such as:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "/* ")
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) " */")
```

You can add this to your `.emacs` file,

```
(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  (c-set-style "stroustrup")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "/* ")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) " */"))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```

or just:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comment-start "/* "
                                          comment-end   " */")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command like:

```
(defun my-block-comment (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((comment-start "/* ")
        (commend-end " */")
        (comment-style 'aligned))
    (comment-region start end)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dLine-Comments.html):

> **26.5.2 Multiple Lines of Comments**
>
> If you are typing a comment and wish to continue it to another line, type <kbd>M-j</kbd> or <kbd>C-M-j</kbd> (`comment-indent-new-line`). This breaks the current line, and inserts the necessary comment delimiters and indentation to continue the comment.
>
> For languages with closing comment delimiters (e.g., `*/` in C), the exact behavior of <kbd>M-j</kbd> depends on the value of the variable `comment-multi-line`. If the value is `nil`, the command closes the comment on the old line and starts a new comment on the new line. Otherwise, it opens a new line within the current comment delimiters.